# Pandas read_csv by remote server ip address

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Dev environ is, say, 178.50.0.180 [A] and target folder is E:\MyName @ 178.50.0.170 [B]

OS: Redhat for [A], Windows Server 2012 for [B]
from [A] ping [B] works fine

How do I read I .csv file in target folder of [B]? Examples I have seen read the url into string literal and pass to read_csv, I have tried:

```
df = pd.read_csv("178.50.0.170\\E\\MyName\\test.csv")

error: FileNotFoundError
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try using raw string with forward slash.

**Ex:**

```
df = pd.read_csv(r"\\178.50.0.170\E\MyName\test.csv")
```